# Two HTML buttons set the same way but one doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm making a dynamic form where the user an add and remove inputs from buttons, however one of these buttons does have a onclick event while the other doesn't despite them being set up exactly set up the same.

I've tried using `<button>` and changing the function to a `console.log` but the "Add Answer Option" button never gets an onclick event.

```js
//add and remove buttons
        var addButton = document.createElement('input'); addButton.type = "button"
        var removeButton = document.createElement('input'); removeButton.type = "button"
        addButton.value = "Add Answer Option";
        removeButton.value = "Remove Answer Option";
        var buttonLi = document.createElement('li');
        buttonLi.innerHTML = "<br>"
        buttonLi.appendChild(addButton);
        buttonLi.innerHTML += ' ';
        buttonLi.appendChild(removeButton);

        var buttonUL = document.createElement('ul');
        this.mainElement.appendChild(buttonUL);

        buttonLi.style = "list-style-type: none;";
        buttonUL.appendChild(buttonLi);

        addButton.onclick = function() {quiz.questions[id].addAnswerOption();}
        removeButton.onclick = function() {quiz.questions[id].removeAnswerOption();}
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bh7tsxqu/

The Add button should add an answer option but it does not. The remove button should remove answer options and it does.

Comment: What is quiz.questions[id] and are you sure that addAnswerOption() exists in that object?

Comment: @AjayGupta Yes. `quiz.questions[id]` just refers to the object we're working in because I have having some issues just defining `this.removeAnswerOption` as the oncall function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using innerHtml property to add content. It removes the listeners when you add a space between buttons. To make your code work remove this line:

```
buttonLi.innerHTML += ' ';
```

and use CSS to add a space between buttons.

Or you can use the insertAdjacentHTML method for adding the space between buttons.

```
buttonLi.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',' ');
```

You can read more about it here: [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Answer (score 0):

I just gave the buttons IDs and used those IDs as selectors for the addition of your onclick event.

Specifically this is what I added.

```
var rmButID = document.getElementById('rmBut');
var addButID = document.getElementById('addBut');
```

And this is what I modified.

```
var addButton = document.createElement('input'); addButton.type = "button"; addButton.id = "addBut"
var removeButton = document.createElement('input'); removeButton.type = "button"; removeButton.id = "rmBut"
```

Here it is all together.

```
var addButton = document.createElement('input'); addButton.type = "button"; addButton.id = "addBut"
var removeButton = document.createElement('input'); removeButton.type = "button"; removeButton.id = "rmBut"
addButton.value = "Add Answer Option";
removeButton.value = "Remove Answer Option";
var buttonLi = document.createElement('li');
buttonLi.innerHTML = "<br>"
buttonLi.appendChild(addButton);
buttonLi.innerHTML += ' ';
buttonLi.appendChild(removeButton);

var buttonUL = document.createElement('ul');
this.mainElement.appendChild(buttonUL);

buttonLi.style = "list-style-type: none;";
buttonUL.appendChild(buttonLi);
var rmButID = document.getElementById('rmBut');
var addButID = document.getElementById('addBut');
addButID.onclick = function() {quiz.questions[id].addAnswerOption();}
rmButID.onclick = function() {quiz.questions[id].removeAnswerOption();}
```